# ODBC -SQL Server Error 17 e SQL Server Erro 2

Tags: odbc, driver

Existe uma aplicação BI em uma estação que tem uma conexão ODBC configurada para buscar o banco de dados em outro servidor. Caso eu abra o BI no servidor onde está o banco de dados SQL e realizar processos de teste de conexões, importação, consultas consigo retorno positivo. Porem, se fizer o mesmo processo no servidor que não esta o banco de dados SQL ocorre o erro de não encontrar o servidor de banco.

Com essas situações realizei o teste de conexão ODBC e é apresentado a seguinte mensagem. 
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Alguém já corrigiu este erro?

Até mais

Comment: Já tentou seguir esses passos descritos em [KB818047](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/818047/pt-br)?

Comment: QMechanic73 já realizei os passos mas não foi suficiente.

Comment: Qual a versão do SQL Server? com `telnet <server-ip> 1433` consegue ter sucesso?

Comment: Após alguns teste e refeito o processo de conexão foi identificado que a conexão ODBC necessitava da inclusão da instância do SQL. No caso ficaria o IP 192.1.1.1\SQL2014. Assim que foi incluso a instância a conexão retornou. Até mais

Comment: Se quiser postar uma resposta explicando como você conseguiu, isso seria importante para outras pessoas que tivessem o mesmo problema que o seu.

Answer (score 1):

Assim que realizamos o acesso ao SQL Server é informado a tela (Conectar ao Servidor) de login. No campo NOME DO SERVIDOR, exemplo, 192.1.1.1. Este nome é informado nas configurações ODBC, mas gerava o erro na print.

Refazendo os passos iniciais de configuração de banco foi visto que o nome do banco estava alterado, havia uma instância 192.1.1.1\SQL2014. Esta instância foi incluído na configuração OBDC e aí sim foi possível conectar novamente.